# After Adding MathJax plugin in ckeditor ,custom shortcut keys are not working

Tags: ckeditor, mathjax, keyboard-shortcuts

In ckeditor i have added mathjax plugin ,after adding it ,my custom shortcut keys are not working

Answer (score 0):

the mistake i had done was by replace extraplug in ,while writing code like
config.extraPlugins = 'keystrokes';
config.extraPlugins = 'mathjax';

it will replace keystrokes plugin 
right way to use multiple plugin in ckeditor is 
**config.extraPlugins = 'keystrokes,mathjax';**